# Rails Devise: Login from a different domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have search everywhere but I can't seem to find the right answer for my problem. So here goes.

I have 2 domains....

http://www.mywebsite.com/ and
http://app.mywebsite.com/

Those two domains are in two different rails apps.

Devise resides in app.mywebsite.com. I have a login/signup form in www.mywebsite.com that will connect to app.website.com. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to share the `model` devise session

Try this

Just modify the `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```
Yourapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_Yourapp_session', :domain => '.mywebsite.com'
```

It works on my applications.

UPDATE

For my answer above, I only tried in one application but different schema, and it works.

Devise model not works if you not put gem devise. :D

If different application, you need `www.mywebsite.com` access to database of `mywebsite.com` Or you can use SSO for your applications.

I think you need this :

1. [Multiple Applications with Devise, Omniauth and Single Sign On](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/)
2. [sso-devise-omniauth-provider](https://github.com/joshsoftware/sso-devise-omniauth-provider)

Some similar questions :

1. [Single logon with different applications approach ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11351484/1297435)
2. [How to pass devise sign_in information into different application with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14648859/1297435)
3. [OmniAuth Single Sign On with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8205927/1297435)

Comment: Should I also put devise in 'www.mywebsite.com'?

Comment: `www.mywebsites.com` is the subdomain of the `mywebsites.com`, so you just put `.mywebsites.com`, because it already includes all subdomains.

Comment: What I meant was, should I also inlcude devise gem in my 'www.mywebsite.com' app?

Comment: I've updated the answer, sorry if the answer does not help, but I've given some references that you may require